# Estimating the value of $\ln2$ using $e^3$ and $2^{10}$

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, estimation

I found this question in an old MAT paper but I'm not getting very far.

You are given that $e^3$ is approximately $20$ and that $2^{10}$ is approximately $1000$. Using this information a student can obtain an approximate value for $\ln2$. which of the following is it?

a) $7/10$

b) $9/13$

c) $38/55$

d) $41/59$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$e^3 \approx 20 = (1000)^{\frac{1}{3}} \times 2 \approx 2^{\frac{10}{3}} \times 2 = 2^{\frac{13}{3}}$. So taking natural logarithms gives

$ 3= \frac{13 \ln 2 }{3}$ and solving gives $\ln 2 \approx \frac{9}{13}$.

[Just saw already answered in comments.]

Comment: should be $3 \approx \frac{13 \ln 2}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

We have the system

$$
\ln 2 + \ln 10 \approx 3\\
10\ln 2-3\ln10 \approx 0
$$

solving for $\ln 2, \ln 10$ we have

$$
\ln2\approx \frac{9}{13}\\
\ln 10 \approx \frac{30}{13}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$2^{10} \approx 1000 = 10^3$ taking the log of both sides $10\ln 2 \approx 3\ln 10.$

Also from the given information and taking the log of both sides $e^3 \approx 20\implies 3 \approx \ln 20 = \ln 2+\ln 10$

Substitute the value of $\ln 10$ from one equation into the other will let you solve for $\ln 2$

$\ln 10 \approx 3 - \ln 2\\
10\ln 2 \approx 3(3-\ln 2)\\
13\ln 2 \approx 9\\
\ln 2 \approx \frac {9}{13}$